# max size of java.nio.MappedByteBuffer

Tags: java, nio, bytebuffer

I just want to make sure the max size of MappedByteBuffer is Integer.MAX_VALUE and there is no way to create a buffer of size 0x80000000. Although the index within this range can be represented by a value of "int" type, this size is not allowed by the specification of "java.nio", right? Thanks!

Comment: The question is answered in the Javadoc. See FileChannel.map(). Not much effort put into this question.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation to FileChannel.map() explicitly states that the size of the mapped region cannot be greater than Integer.MAX_VALUE. The method (presumably) takes a long parameter for consistency with other file API calls or for future expansion, but in reality ByteBuffer indices generally are defined to be ints.

You should be able to map a region *starting* beyond that value, though, so in principle you could map a larger file by having several mapped portions.